# How to have two documents with same numbering sequence (e.g., figure numbers, lemma numbers)?

Tags: cross-referencing

I have two different documents: `main.tex` and `appendix.tex` in latex. Is it possible to keep the numbering sequences (e.g., figure number, lemma number) of these documents synchronized? For example, Figures 1 - 4 are in the `main.tex`, and thus if I add a new figure in `appendix.tex`, the starting number will be Figure 5. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the document as separate pieces (for example, a file for each chapter), and then

```
\documentclass{book}
% Title and stuff
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Each part does just start with the corresponding `\chapter{...}` command, just like you did cut it out of the full source. Note that `\include{}` starts the contents on a new page.

This way numbering (of chapters, but also other numbered structures) follows naturally.

Further benefit is that the individual pieces are more manageable to edit, and crossreferences from e.g one chapter to another work with no hassle.
You might even go further, having each chapter `\include{}`ing a file with exercises, or split it into sections.